# QQuickPaintedItem mouseReleaseEvent gets only called after doubleclick

Tags: qt

I've derived a class from `QQuickPaintedItem` in which I want to handle the `mousePressEvent` and the `mouseReleasEvent` (and also the `mouseMoveEvent` but that is not my prolem now).

The `mousePressEvent` gets called properly everytime the left mouse button is pressed. But the `mouseReleaseEvent` gets only called after a double click. What I expected is to get the event everytime the button is released. How can I change this?

This is what I do:

```
MyView::MyView(QQuickItem *parent):
    QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
{
    setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::LeftButton);
}

void MyView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *evt)
{
    //gets called after every single mouse click
    qDebug("mousePressEvent");
    if(evt->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        //do something...
        evt->accept();
    }
    else
    {
        evt->ignore();
    }
    QQuickPaintedItem::mousePressEvent(evt);
}

void MyView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *evt)
{
    //gets only called when releasing the mouse button after a double click
    qDebug("mouseReleaseEvent");
    if(evt->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        //do something...
        evt->accept();
    }
    else
    {
        evt->ignore();
    }
    QQuickPaintedItem::mouseReleaseEvent(evt);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found the solution!

Calling the base class implementation is a bad idea since the base class simply calls `ignore()` on the event. Here is the base class implementation:

```
    void QWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
    {
        ev->ignore();
    }
    void QWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
    {
        ev->ignore();
    }
```

So this is how it works:

```
    MyView::MyView(QQuickItem *parent):
        QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
    {
        setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::LeftButton);
    }

    void MyView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *evt)
    {
        //gets called after every single mouse click
        qDebug("mousePressEvent");
        if(evt->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            //do something...
            evt->accept();
        }
        else
        {
            evt->ignore();
        }
        //DON'T DO THIS:
        //QQuickPaintedItem::mousePressEvent(evt);
    }

    void MyView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *evt)
    {
        //now gets called with every mouse release since we don't call the base class any more
        qDebug("mouseReleaseEvent");
        if(evt->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            //do something...
            evt->accept();
        }
        else
        {
            evt->ignore();
        }
        //DON'T DO THIS:
        //QQuickPaintedItem::mouseReleaseEvent(evt);
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks! Do the docs specifically say not to do this somewhere? I normally always call the base class implementation for completeness.

Comment: No. Unfortunately not. I also always call the base implementation. And usually one should always do that unless you really know why you have to omit it. But that means that you also have know what happens in your base class. I think that's bad style.
But usually I also do it on top of the overridden method. And now as I had a look at it again I can't remember why I put it on the end. On top it shouldn't hurt (but I don't know what "magic" happens inside the ignore call). I'm not working with Qt any more so I might check this at home.